# How to block command prompt from showing my password while I'm inputting it to my java program

Tags: java, console, password-protection

So I have this application, where I read users input from command prompt, and when user is inputting his/her password, I would like to hide it such that everyone else cant see it like this:

```
Please enter your password below
this is password
```

I would like to show it like this:

```
Please enter your password below
****************
```

So is there any way of doing this in java console application?

Comment: @Dlotan Duplicate! why? lots of questions here, may be this guy wasnt able to find related Questions on SO..are you a cop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Console` class, it has `readPassword()`

Syntax:

```
public char[] readPassword(String fmt,Object... args)
```

Provides a formatted prompt, then reads a password or passphrase from the console with echoing disabled.

**Parameters:**

> ***fmt*** - A format string as described in Format string syntax for the prompt text.
>
> ***args*** - Arguments referenced by the format specifiers in the format string. If there are more  arguments than format specifiers,
>   the extra arguments are ignored. The maximum number of arguments is
>   limited by the maximum dimension of a Java array as defined by the
>   Java Virtual Machine Specification.
>
> ***Returns*** - A character array containing the password or passphrase read from the console, not including any line-termination
>   characters, or null if an end of stream has been reached.

Comment: Just formatted your answer for readability.

Comment: @LittleChild no issues cheers

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the answer pointed in the comment:

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Main {

public void passwordExample() {        
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get Console instance");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    console.printf("Testing password%n");
    char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter your secret password: ");
    console.printf("Password entered was: %s%n", new String(passwordArray));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().passwordExample();
}
}
```

The thing to notice is that you are getting back a `char[]` and not a `String`. This is for security reasons and there is another great answer on this same topic on SO. You should destroy this `char[]` by overwriting it after your work is done. `String`s can stay a longer time in memory till the GC collects them and this can be a security risk.

Run the example from the command line and not from an IDE. It may not work.